# How correctly return a Promise from this Angular service method calling an external API?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-promise, angular-observable

I am working on an Angular application and I am finding the following problem. I have this service method:

```
  // MANUALLY VERIFY\UNVERIFY EMAIL ADDRESS FOR USER REGISTRATION:
  verifyUnverifyEmailAddress(uid:String): Promise<any[]> {
    this.apiCallUrl = this.apiBaseUrl + "/verifyUnverifyEmailAddress?uid=" + uid;

    //let finalResult = null;

    this.http.get<any>(this.apiCallUrl).subscribe((result) => {
      console.log("VERIFY\UNVERIFY USER EMAIL: ", result);
      return result.toPromise();
    });
  }
```

The problem is that I am trying to return my Promise inside the **subscribe()** arrow function (because I have to ensure to return after that I have actually retrieved my data. But doing in this way I obtain the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/auth/auth.service.ts:237:43 - error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

237   verifyUnverifyEmailAddress(uid:String): Promise<any[]> {
```

How can I restructure my code to correctly return my Promise after that the API obtained data from the backend?

Another doubt is: I have to use this promise to update the status of a component (the value returned into my component is used to say if the email address of a specific user was verified or not). I have the following doubt: for a use case like this is it better to return and use a Promise or return an Obserable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no visible advantages converting an observable to a promise unless explicitly required. For eg. some API expects a promise instead of an observable. In all other cases, I'd say it's better to use the observable as is.

You could return the observable from the service and subscribe in the controller

Service

```js
verifyUnverifyEmailAddress(uid:String): Observable<any> { // <-- return observable
  this.apiCallUrl = this.apiBaseUrl + "/verifyUnverifyEmailAddress?uid=" + uid;
  return this.http.get<any>(this.apiCallUrl);
}
```

You could then subscribe in the component

Component

```js
someFunc()
  this.someService.verifyUnverifyEmailAddress('sample').subscribe({
    next: (response) => {
      console.log(response);
      this.response = response;
      // use `response`
    },
    error: (error) => {
      // handle HTTP errors
    }
  });
}
```

---

If for any reason you wish to convert to a Promise, you could use RxJS `lastValueFrom` or `firstValueFrom` functions

Component

```js
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

async someFunc()
  this.response = await lastValueFrom(this.someService.verifyUnverifyEmailAddress('sample'));
  ...
}
```

---

<sup>Note: `toPromise` is being deprecated in RxJS 7 and will be gone in RxJS 8.</sup>

Comment: There should actually be no reason to convert Observables to Promise in angular